# I keep getting a 403 from Firebase storge when trying to read image files

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm having a hard time understanding the whole token part of Firebase uploads.

I want to simply upload use avatars, save them to the database and then read them at the client side.

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
storageRef.child(`images/user-avatars/${user.uid}`).put(imageObj);
```

Then, in my cloud function, I grab the new url like this:

```
exports.writeFileToDatabase = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(object => {
  const bucket = defaultStorage.bucket();
  const path = object.name as string;
  const file = bucket.file(path);

  return file
    .getSignedUrl({
      action: "read",
      expires: "03-17-2100"
    })
    .then(results => {
      const url = results[0];
      const silcedPath = path.split("/");

      return db
        .collection("venues")
        .doc(silcedPath[1])
        .set({ images: FieldValue.arrayUnion(url) }, { merge: true });
    });
});
```

I've enabled `IAM` in the Google APIs platform, and have added `Cloud functions service agent` to the `App Engine default service account`.

I feel like the exact same configuration has worked before, butt now it sometimes doesn't even write the new url or I get 403 trying to read it. I can't find any explanations or errors to what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:
Forgot to add this piece of code, but `FieldValue` is set at the top of the document as

```
const FieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;
```

EDIT:
This the exact error I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()`

And I just got it when I've tried to use this link, which has been generated automatically by the function above, as the source for an image component:

`https://storage.googleapis.com/frothin-weirdos.appspot.com/images/user_avatars/yElCIVY4bAY5g5LnoOBhqN6mDNv2?GoogleAccessId=frothin-weirdos%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1742169600&Signature=qSqPuuY4c5xmdnpvfZh39Pw3Vyu2B%2FbGMD1rQwHDBUZTAnKwP11MaOFQt%2BTV53krkIgvJgQT0Xl3UUxkngmW9785fUri75SSPoBk0z4DKyZnEBLxgTGRE8MzmXadQ%2BHDJ3rSI8IkkoomdnANpLsPN9oySshZ1h4BfOBvAmK0hQ4Gge1glH7qhxFjVWfX3tovZoL8e2smhuCRXxDsZtJh0ihbIeZUEnX8lGic%2B9IT6y4OskS2ZlrZNjvM10hcEesoPdHsT4oCvfhCNbUcJcueRKfsWlDCd9m6qmf42WVOc7UI0nE0oEvysMutWY971GVRKTLwIXRnTLSNOr6fSvJE3Q%3D%3D`

Comment: "I get 403 trying to read it" Please edit your question to include the exact error message, and stack trace, and where you get this error.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added both